# How to know iFrame Id or name present on web page?

Tags: iframe, selenium-webdriver

I am automating a web application which has multiple iFrames on page using selenium web driver. I have identified that the element is iframe but I am stuck and don;t know the the id of iframe. How to get iFrame name or Id on web page?

Comment: you need the ID of a specific Iframe or the ID of all the iframes?

Comment: Add the relevant HTML with min 2 levels hierarchy... If you cannot get an unique id or name you will need to use a CSS or xpath

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [ask] page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: I need Id of a specific iFrame on web page. I have tried it by viewing View source but couldn't find it. That is the weird way to get all iFrames present on web page and get specific iFrame using index value. Please let me know if there is any other way to find iFrame id.

Answer (score 0):

There are id and name attributes for iframe element in your source code. If there not there you can use index value.